# Locale change on an ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I get a different locale when I do an ajax call,

When I call this function on page load it gives me es_ES because my site is on the Spanish locale.

```
   function getCareerHtml(){
            global $locale;
            echo $locale.; //print es_ES
    }
```

When I call The above function using ajax it gives me the en_US locale.

```
       // js function
       function ajaxGetGlobalSerch(page){

    jQuery.ajax({

        url:POST http://localhost/mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type:'POST',

        data:'action=ajaxGetCareerAction&page=',
        success:function(results)
        {
        alert("success");

        }
    });

}


   //function.php
   add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxGetCareerAction', 'getCareerHtml');
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxGetCareerAction','getCareerHtml');
   function getCareerHtml(){
            global $locale;
            echo $locale.; //print en_US
                           // but it should print es_ES because site is set to spanish locale
    }
```

Comment: BTW you have `$locale.;` you will want to remove the `.`

Comment: It looks like #1 returns the client language and #2 returns admin language.

Comment: I have no further experience with wordpress development, but have you tried [get_locale()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_locale) instead of the `$locale`? Seems this is the appropriate way to get the current locale.